# Which vim version can I use?

Tags: unity, vim, gvim

I recently installed vim on Ubuntu (14.04) with Unity. As it turns out, vim does not support yanking text to the clipboard (usind `+` or `*`). I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60200/how-to-copy-data-between-different-instances-of-vim) that I have to install GVim in order to add this capability to vim.

Using `apt-cache search` I did not find a package named `gvim` but the two packages `vim-gnome` and `vim-gtk`. As I understand it, those are two different types of graphical interface. Since I use Ubuntu with Unity, I am unsure which one is suitable for me.

What exactly are the differences between those two packages and which one can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two packages are mostly the same. Both will work perfectly fine with the Unity desktop.

One difference is the set of libraries that they are linked with for the GVim's graphical components, so the look of buttons, menus, and file dialogs may be different.

Another difference is desktop session support. According to [Vim's description of its GNOME GUI](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#GNOME), the `vim-gnome` version should save and restore its session when logging out of a desktop session, and prompt about unsaved files as well.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/281972/70254) for a complete list of all available `vim-*` packages.