# Why is my vimtutor blank?

Tags: vim

I want to learn `Vim`. The vast majority of people advise me to use `vimtutor`. I downloaded the package and ran it, but I just get given a blank screen.

[image]

I see on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhdWEQb58Q0) that there should be tons of things on there. But I am not getting it...How can I fix this?

Originally, I was told by the terminal to install `vim-runtime` in order to run `vimtutor`, and I did and it ran, albeit with a blank screen. I was able to run this tutorial after I installed `vim-gtk`. Anyone know why it didn't show up the first time?

Comment: It is sort of a long-standing problem see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/255847 Try installing vim (and removing vim-tiny). You may also need to log out and back in for some of your environmental variable to be updated.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I fixed it by installing `vim-gtk`, it was very frustrating though...thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @dayuloli can you post the solution that worked for you as an answer and accept it so this question is no longer listed as unanswered?

Comment: @mtmiller I have instead posted the solution that resolved the issue in the question itself, but I still do not know the reason for why it happened. So I will leave it open for now.

Comment: @dayuloli before you installed `vim-gtk`, what `vim*` packages did you have installed? Did you only have the `vim-tiny` variant installed?

Comment: @mtmiller I had whatever came with ubuntu 14.04. I don't remember installing anything else.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `vimtutor` command requires a Vim that has Vim scripting support compiled in. For those familiar with building Vim from source, this requires at least the `normal` feature set or higher.

The default Ubuntu desktop installation only includes the [vim-tiny](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim-tiny) [image: Install vim-tiny] package, which is Vim compiled with almost all optional features disabled. This variant of Vim provides enough to run `vi` with all of the basic functionality of a vi-compatible editor, but none of the power of Vim. Since it does not have Vim scripting support enabled, it cannot work with the `vimtutor` command. You should install one of the more capable Vim variant packages instead:

- [vim](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim) [image: Install vim]
- [vim-athena](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim-athena) [image: Install vim-athena]
- [vim-gnome](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim-gnome) [image: Install vim-gnome]
- [vim-gtk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim-gtk) [image: Install vim-gtk]
- [vim-nox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim-nox) [image: Install vim-nox]

Any one of these packages provide a Vim that is capable of running `vimtutor`. For more about the differences between these Vim variants, see the following questions:

- [What is the difference between the different vim packages available in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/281886/70254)
- [What features does vim-tiny have?](https://askubuntu.com/q/104138/70254)
- [Difference between vim-gtk and vim-gnome](https://askubuntu.com/q/33260/70254)
- [Which vim version can I use?](https://askubuntu.com/q/457210/70254)

Answer (score 4):

You need to install vim before using vimtutor!

Run the following command in the Terminal prompt!

```
sudo apt install vim
```

Now use vimtutor for learning. Happy Learning!

Comment: This solution worked for me and was more immediately useful than the accepted solution. Granted, the accepted solution explained the problem better.